# Magento 1.9.x rwd-theme - Trouble working with RWD_icon_sprite.psd

Tags: magento

I have downloaded the sprite.psd from magento directly and edited the icon the way I wanted. The issue i am having is getting it to display. I save as icon_sprite.png and upoad to /rwd/mytheme/default/images but the icon does not change on my webpage

Comment: I have made the icon_sprite@2x.png file aswell, and tried flushing all cache including image cache

Comment: Have change this images in other places as well.

Comment: and by other places you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The path where you uploaded the image is wrong. Theme images should be under `/skin/frontend/<package>/<theme>/images/`. In your case, package is obviously `rwd` and theme is `mytheme`.

This means that the path for upload should be `/skin/frontend/rwd/mytheme/images/`.

Lastly don't forget to set `mytheme` under *System -> Configuration -> General -> Design -> Themes -> Skin (Images / CSS)*.

Comment: sorry I mistyped the path. I'm using a custom package that defaults back to rwd through .xml, the correct path is skin/frontend/custompackage/customtheme(default in my case)/images/{file}

Comment: @rsaari: If the path is correct then it must be the configuration (I presume no core code regarding theme loading was changed). Double check filename and configuration System -> Configuration -> General -> Design. You can also share a screen shot of your configuration, so I can take a look.